# How to store functions inside Javascript object that have a global scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tampermonkey

I am attempting to run a userscript that changes the DOM based upon server-side variables. 
Initial updateStatus() returns the correct values, however as the server changes the variables, the variables inside of the glowIf conditions do not change.

If I run these conditions externally from the object, like this:

```
 function updateStatus(){
   console.log(var1 === var2);
 };
```

everything works fine, but once I store them inside an object, the condition doesn't update. Like this:

```
 function updateStatus(){
   console.log(foo.condition);
 };
```

HTML:

```
 <div id='foo'>
   This condition is true
 </div>
 <div id='bar'>
   This condition is false
 </div>

 <!-- Server sets values of var1 and var2-->
 <-- example var1 = 4, var2 = 4 -->
```

CSS:

```
 .glow {
   border: 1px solid gold;
 }
```

JS:

```
  // Update as server changes values
  const refreshRate = setInterval(updateStatus, 1000); 

  // Example Object
  const itemDef = [{
      name: 'foo',
      condition: (var1 === var2)
    },
    {
      name: 'bar',
      condition: false }];

  // Check Conditions
  function updateStatus() {
    jQuery.each(itemDef, function(i, val) {
      if (val.condition) {
        $('#' + val.name).addClass('glow');
      } else {
        $('#' + val.name).removeClass('glow');
      }
    });
  }
```

I can't seem to update the variables after the initial condition check. 
They are serverside variables that are continually updated every second.

Here is a larger example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/byhx620r/5/

Comment: Your fiddle is close to the correct way of doing it. Add a `()` to the end of your `glowIf` inside `updateStatus`.

The reason `button2` evaluates to `true` is because functions are truthy. (the first button should actually be named `button1` btw).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because the value of `var1 === var2` gets evaluated only once when you define the array, the result get stored and any information about how the value has been got is lost.

What you want, probably, is to check the condition every time you access the `condition` property.

You have two ways:

- Use a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) (not advised)
- Use a method in place of a static property

I propose you this solution:

Change condition from booleans to *functions that return booleans*:

```
const itemDef = [{
      name: 'foo',
      condition: () => var1 === var2
    },
    {
      name: 'bar',
      condition: () => false }];
```

And finally, check the value of the condition by calling the method:

```
if (val.condition())
```

---

Ps. Why do you use `JQuery.each` in place of `itemDef.forEach`? It's more readable, plain js and has a great compatibility with all the modern browsers

Comment: This worked beautifully, thank you! 

In regards to the $.each vs forEach, I honestly didn't know forEach existed. I assumed I was going to have to create a larger for-loop. I will definitely use forEach now!